# How can I add items from a listbox to a list by clicking a button without any codebehind?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox

I am new to MVVM, and also fairly new to WPF. As a matter of fact I started programming just a few months ago. MVVM is really dng my head in with the binding concept, and I have been trying for days now to just simply make an application that allows you to select an item from a listbx, and when you click on the add button the selected item should be saved in a new list.  The second listbox displays the latest items added, and you can select an item and delete it by using another button. ususally I would go for the click event and decorate my codebehind with pretty little methods, but I really want to learn how to do all this by using bindings and no codebehind. 
I would be extremly happy for any help, and please remember that I am new to this and I really want to keep it as simple as possible :)
with kind regards Daniela

```
<WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin=" 10">
   <ListBox x:Name="Firstbox" 
            Width="100"
            ItemsSource="{Binding FoodList}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name" >
   </ListBox>
   <Button Margin="10 >Select</Button>
   <ListBox Width="100"></ListBox>
```

private List _foodList;

```
    public List<FoodItem> FoodList
    {
        get { return _foodList; }
        set { _foodList = value; }
    }

    private List<FoodItem> _newFoodList;

    public List<FoodItem> NewFoodList
    {
        get { return _newFoodList; }
        set { _newFoodList = value; }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        InitializeCommands();
        GetFood();
    }
    private void GetFood()
    {
        FoodList = new List<FoodItem>()
        {
            new FoodItem() {Name="Applepie"}, 
            new FoodItem() {Name="Scones"}
        };
    }
```

Comment: Don't have so much code :( Have no idea how to do this :(

Comment: if i may suggest you could read a book about MVVM and then you will be able to do this easily. But to help you right now to accomplish this task you would have to implement ICommands and then bind them to your buttons command property. It is very easy to do and you can find a lot of examples to help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- first, you need to replace the `List`s with `ObservableCollection`s, so that the UI can detect when new items are added.
- Add a `SelectedItem` property to your ViewModel:

  ```
  private FoodItem _selectedItem;
  public FoodItem SelectedItem
  {
      get { return _selectedItem;}
      set
      {
          _selectedItem = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
      }
  }
  ```
- bind the `SelectedItem` property of the 1st `ListBox` to this property:

  ```
  <ListBox Width=" 100" x:Name="Firstbox"
           ItemsSource="{Binding FoodList}"
           DisplayMemberPath="Name"
           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
  ```
- bind your 2nd `ListBox` to the `NewFoodList` property
- create a command in your ViewModel:

  ```
  private DelegateCommand _addItemCommand;
  public ICommand AddItemCommand
  {
      get
      {
          if (_addItemCommand == null)
          {
              _addItemCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddItem);
          }
          return _addItemCommand;
      }
  }

  void AddItem()
  {
      if (SelectedItem != null)
          NewFoodList.Add(SelectedItem);
  }
  ```
- And finally, bind the button's `Command` property to the `AddItemCommand` property:

  ```
  <Button Margin="10" Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}" >Select</Button>
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I get : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at the AddItem method, do you have any idae why?

Comment: When i debug I can see that an item is selected, but it is not added to the NewFoodList.

Comment: @Daniela, you need to initialize the NewFoodList property in the constructor: `NewFoodList = new ObservableCollection<FoodItem>();`

Comment: *blush* that was embarassing! Thank you :)